# Exactness is often an open condition.  How often?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal C$ denote an abelian category.  Consider a formal $\mathbb Z$-graded object $V_\bullet$ in $\mathcal C$, by which I simply mean a $\mathbb Z$-indexed list $n\mapsto V_n$ of objects.  A *differential* on $V_\bullet$ is a sequence of maps $\partial : V_n \to V_{n-1}$ such that $\partial^2 = 0$; for example, the sequence of all $0$s works.  A differential is *exact* if for every $n$, $\ker \partial|_{V_n} = \partial(V_{n+1})$.
Clearly, for fixed $V_\bullet \in \mathcal C$, the collection of differentials is the intersection of some quadrics in some abelian group.  I have less of an idea of what type of space the exact differentials constitute, which is one of the motivations for my question.

Thus, fix a $\mathbb Z$-graded object $V_\bullet \in \mathcal C$.  Suppose that you fix also an exact differential $\partial_0$.  There are many situations where one is interested in "varying" $\partial_0$ to some new differential $\partial$.  One situation that arises is the "formal deformation": we can formally extend $\mathcal C$ to a new category $\mathcal C[\![\hbar]\!]$ by tensoring every hom set with $\mathbb Z[\![\hbar]\!]$, and then consider differentials $\partial$ on $V_\bullet[\![\hbar]\!]$ such that $\partial = \partial_0 \mod\hbar$.  I can also imagine more algebrogeometric contexts: I expect that there is a natural way to give the hom spaces in an abelian category, and thus the space of differentials, the structure of affine algebraic varieties; then I could probe this space by, say, local Artinian rings.  I could also, of course, probe non-infinitesimal neighborhoods.

In any case, one should expect that if $\partial_0$ is exact that $\partial$ is "close enough" to $\partial_0$, then $\partial$ is also exact.  I know how to prove a special case of this.  Say that $\mathcal C$ *has the Axiom of Choice* if every epimorphism in $\mathcal C$ splits.  Then, since $\mathcal C$ is abelian, it must also have the Axiom of "co-Choice", and one can always choose a deformation retraction of any complex onto its homology, for example, and also one can always choose an isomorphism between a (Hausdorff exhaustive) filtered object and its associated graded.  Under these conditions, I can prove that formal deformations of exact differentials remain exact.  Another somewhat trivial example is when $V_\bullet = (V_0,V_1)$ is two terms long.  Then an exact differential is an isomorphism $\partial_0 : V_1 \overset\sim\to V_0$.  Consider the situation when $\mathcal C$ is, say, the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces.  Then the space of isomorphisms is naturally a Zariski-open (and hence analytically open, if we are over $\mathbb R$) subset of the space of all maps.

> **Question:**  Is there a way to give the the space of differentials on $V_\bullet$ a natural (Zariski, say, but I'm agnostic) topology, perhaps under some conditions on $\mathcal C$, and if so, how?  Under what conditions does the slogan "exactness is an open condition" hold?  As a special case, does it hold for "infinitesimal" (either in the local-Artinian or $\hbar$ sense) deformations in the absence of Choice?

A further version of my question recognizes the fact that many categories are naturally enriched in topological abelian groups; categories of Banach spaces, for example.  Then one can also ask: when is exactness an open condition for "analytic" topologies?

Lest you say that exactness is *always* an open condition, let me end with a trivial parting comment.  I could, if I so chose, give every space the indiscrete topology.  For this topology, exactness certainly is not open, as deforming all the way to $\partial = 0$ would be a "small" deformation.

Comment: The set of complexes of vector spaces of given finite dimension vector "are" an affine space, and the dimension of their cohomology groups is a lower (upper? I never know which) semi-continuous function. Since it is possitive, that gives your continuity in that case.

Comment: Regarding your parting comment, I think it is reasonable to require that the zero element be closed in any topologized hom space.

Comment: Mariano, I think you mean affine variety, with equations $d^2=0$.

Comment: "I expect that there is a natural way to give the hom spaces in an abelian category, and thus the space of differentials, the structure of affine algebraic varieties;" I am not sure if this works without any assumption on the abelian category.

Comment: @Mariano: Right, for finite-dimensional vector spaces I know how to do everything I've asked. Already for infinite-dimensional vector spaces, though, I know how to prove semicontinuity for "infinitesimal" open neighborhoods, but I don't know enough about infinite-dimensional vector spaces to say things finitely...

Comment: ... For abelian groups, I think I can do the infinitesimal case from a spectral-sequence argument, using the fact that the if the associated-graded of a filter abelian group is zero, then the filtered abelian group was already zero; but there, I don't even know "infinitesimal upper semicontinuity" except near exact complexes, and I really don't know how to say non-infinitesimal statements.